# REIN Replacement

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen previous forum posts saying that REIN is deprecated and that a non ROS version was in development. Has this new version been released yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11713/rein-replacement/) by [tpr464](https://answers.ros.org/users/1289/tpr464/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See ecto.willowgarage.com .  NOTE: it is still under development.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-01-12**:
@kwc - What is the current status of the ecto project?  Is it ready for end users to start playing with it or is still in flux?  For example, the build instructions found here (http://ecto.willowgarage.com/releases/amoeba-beta4/README.html) fail on the third step, 'git submodule update', with the error "Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'git@github.com:willowgarage/catkin.git' into submodule path 'catkin' failed".

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-27**:
@Pi Robot If you use the https interface it should work: https://github.com/willowgarage/catkin.git